# Changing data in Live Data Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `allRecords` - Live Data values obtained from the Room, through the Repository.

I want the `handleSelectedItem` method to change the values of one item in the `LiveData<List<...>>` if it is matched by id.
I tried to do this with Transformation.map (), but this code does not work

```
class RecordListViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: RecordRepository): ViewModel() {
    private var allRecords : LiveData<List<RecordItem>> = Transformations.map(repository.getAllRecording()){
        records -> return@map records.map{ it.toItem()}

    }



    fun getAllRecords() : LiveData<List<RecordItem>>{
        return allRecords
    }

    fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int) {
        Log.d("HandleSelectedItem", "Test1")
        allRecords = Transformations.map(allRecords) { records ->
            return@map records.map {
                if (it.id == id){
                    Log.d("HandleSelectedItem", "Test2")
                    it.copy(isSelected = true)
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("HandleSelectedItem", "Test3")
                    it.copy(isSelected = false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help to solve this problem

**Update**
Here offered `MutableLiveData` instead of `LiveData`.
Then both Repository and Dao should return MutableLiveData

**Repository**

```
fun getAllRecording(): MutableLiveData<List<RecordEntity>> =
        appDatabase.getRecordDao().getAllRecording()
```

**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM record")
fun getAllRecording() : MutableLiveData<List<RecordEntity>>
```

But Room database cannot return MutableLiveData

**Error**

```
D:\Project\VoiceRecording\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\ru\ddstudio\voicerecording\data\database\daos\RecordDao.java:17: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.util.List<ru.ddstudio.voicerecording.data.database.entities.RecordEntity>>).
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.util.List<ru.ddstudio.voicerecording.data.database.entities.RecordEntity>> getAllRecording();
```

**Update2**

```
private val allRecords = MediatorLiveData<List<RecordItem>>().apply {
            val recordsRepository = repository.getAllRecording().map { records -> records.map { it.toItem() } }
            addSource(recordsRepository)
        }
```

Error `addSource()`

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
@MainThread public final fun <S : Any!> addSource(@NonNull p0: LiveData<List<RecordItem>!>, @NonNull p1: (List<RecordItem>!) -> Unit): Unit defined in androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
@MainThread public open fun <S : Any!> addSource(@NonNull p0: LiveData<List<RecordItem>!>, @NonNull p1: Observer<in List<RecordItem>!>): Unit defined in androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
```

Comment: Have you tried making `allRecords` into a `val`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Change var allRecords to val allRecords? And as I will to change allRecords, val same not change

Comment: Well you shouldn't be changing it the way you're changing it now. That's why you should make it `val`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I updated the question regarding your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LiveData` objects should be `val`. Use `MutableLiveData`/ `MediatorLiveData` and `setValue` or `postValue` to change the value in `LiveData`

```
class RecordListViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: RecordRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val allRecords = MediatorLiveData<List<RecordItem>>().apply {
        val recordsLiveData = repository.getAllRecording().map { records -> records.map { it.toItem() } }
        addSource(recordsLiveData) { records -> 
            value = records
        }
    }

    fun getAllRecords() : LiveData<List<RecordItem>> {
        return allRecords
    }

    fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int) {
        Log.d("HandleSelectedItem", "Test1")
        allRecords.value?.let { records ->
            allRecords.value = records.map { it.copy(isSelected = it.id == id) }
        }
    }
}
```

> Then both Repository and Dao should return MutableLiveData

No, it shouldn't. Use `LiveData` in your `DAO` and `Repository`

Comment: Can you edit allRecords? The number of opening brackets does not match the number of closing brackets

Comment: I updated the question regarding your code in Update2

Comment: @danilshik sorry, I had an error in the example. fixed now I hope

Comment: allRecords.value = records. One error: Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly.
Two error: Variable 'allRecords' must be initialized

Comment: @danilshik try `value = records`